# IOS 7 - Web Frame Error - "Expected a type"

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios7

The i am very new to IOS . I have recently upgraded my XCode and after that the below mentioned line of code started giving me error . The error i am getting is WebFrame and the error text reads "Expected a type "

```
- (void)webView:(UIWebView *)sender runJavaScriptAlertPanelWithMessage:(NSString *)message     initiatedByFrame:(WebFrame *)frame;
```

any immediate help is appreciated .
Regards
Sree

Comment: This means that it doesn't know what 'WebFrame' is. Is it a class that you have defined yourself? If so, you'll need to import the header into the file with this error.

Comment: in IOS 6(XCode Verion 4.5.2) this class was in UIKit.Framework-->UITextView.h . But in IOS 7 (Xcode 5.0) the same is missing . Please advise

Comment: Which delegate protocol are you using? i.e. inside the <> of the class you are running this code in.